# Verifying ssl certificate for an https server created with device ip address in java

Tags: java, ssl, https

I created an https server running with device ip addresses and port 8080 in android app with Java.
(Like: 192.168.1.20:8080/something)

Currently I have created sslContext with a self-signed BKS file, of course browsers do not trust this certificate because it is self-signed. I used ZeroSSL to generate an IP address specific ssl certificate but in the "Verify Domain" stage two options are available DNS (CNAME) and Html File Upload. I haven't been able to find and know anything about how I can use these options in my own code.

Are there any other methods besides ZeroSSL? Can you give an idea how I can create a structure?

Also if I successfully verify an SSL certificate for the IP address. What action should I take when the IP address of this android device changes? Because we created the certificate for the state before the IP address changed.

My Create Https Server Code:

```
        try {
            InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(8080);
            Log.i(HttpServerManager.getHttpServerManager().TAG, "HttpServer starting up: ");

            HttpServerManager.getHttpServerManager().httpServer = HttpsServer.create(address, 0);


            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            char[] password = "123456".toCharArray();

            // Initialise the keystore
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
            ks.load(HoneywellApplication.instance().getApplicationContext()
                    .getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.mynewkey), password);

            // Set up the key manager factory
            KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            kmf.init(ks, password);

            // Set up the trust manager factory
            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            tmf.init(ks);

            // Set up the HTTPS context and parameters
            sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
            HttpServerManager.getHttpServerManager().httpServer.setHttpsConfigurator(new HttpsConfigurator(sslContext) {
                public void configure(HttpsParameters params) {
                    try {

                        // Initialise the SSL context
                        SSLContext c = SSLContext.getDefault();
                        SSLEngine engine = c.createSSLEngine();
                        params.setNeedClientAuth(false);
                        params.setCipherSuites(engine.getEnabledCipherSuites());
                        params.setProtocols(engine.getEnabledProtocols());

                        // Get the default parameters
                        SSLParameters defaultSSLParameters = c.getDefaultSSLParameters();
                        params.setSSLParameters(defaultSSLParameters);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Log.e(HttpServerManager.getHttpServerManager().TAG, "HttpsServer configure ex: " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());

                    }
                }
            });

            HttpServerManager.getHttpServerManager().httpServer.createContext("/", new RootHandler());

            HttpServerManager.getHttpServerManager().httpServer.setExecutor(null);
            HttpServerManager.getHttpServerManager().httpServer.start();

            Log.i(HttpServerManager.getHttpServerManager().TAG, "HttpServer started");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```